# "Illegal polymorphic or qualified type" in instance declaration (System-F style trees)

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, typeclass, compiler-directives, system-f

I'm experimenting with implementing System-F-style data structures in Haskell.

I'll use `A <B>` to mean application of a term `A` to a type `B` just to make it unambiguous (also using capitals for types).

Let's say `Tree <T>` is the type of binary trees with values of type `T`. We want to find a type that can act as `Tree <T>`. There are three constructors:

```
EmptyTree <T> : (Tree <T>)
Leaf <T> : T → (Tree <T>)
Branch <T> : (Tree <T>) → (Tree <T>) → (Tree <T>)
```

So, by some cleverness due, I think, to Girard, we can use the following

```
Tree T = ∀ A. A → (T → A) → (A → A → A) → A
```

from which

```
Empty <T>
        = ΛA.λa:A.λf:(T → A).λg:(A → A → A).
            a

Leaf <T> (x:T)
        = ΛA.λa:A.λf:(T → A).λg:(A → A → A).
            f x

Branch <T> (t1:Tree <T>) (t2:Tree <T>)
        = ΛA.λa:A.λf:(T → A).λg:(A → A → A).
            g (t1 <A> a f g) (t2 <A> a f g)
```

I've found out about the directives needed for these things in Haskell, and I don't think I'm missing any. So in Haskell:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
type T t = forall a.a -> (t -> a) -> (a -> a -> a) -> a

empty :: T t
empty = \a _ _ -> a
leaf :: t -> T t
leaf x = \_ f _ -> f x
fork :: T t -> T t -> T t
fork t1 t2 = \a f g -> g (t1 a f g) (t2 a f g)
```

So far, all of this compiles and seems to work. The issue arises when I try to make an instance for `Show` for my `T t` type. I've added more directives:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, TypeSynonymInstances, FlexibleInstances #-}
```

and a function for printing the tree

```
displayTree :: Show t => T t -> String
displayTree t = t displayEmpty show displayFork
```

with appropriate helpers `displayEmpty :: String` and `displayFork :: String -> String -> String`. This also compiles and works (up to prettiness). Now if I try to instantiate `T t` as an instance of `Show`

```
instance Show t => Show (T t) where
    show = displayTree
```

I get the following error when trying to compile:

```
    Illegal polymorphic or qualified type: T t
    In the instance declaration for 'Show (T t)'
```

I (think I) understand the need for `TypeSynonymInstances` and `FlexibleInstances` and the pragmatic reasons for their existence, but I don't understand why my type `T t` *still* can't be declared an instance of `Show`. Is there a way to do this, and what property of `T t` means that this is currently problematic in my code?

Comment: GHC means what it says. Polymorphic types are simply not allowed in instance heads. If you define `Tree` as a newtype then you can create instances for it.

Comment: Perhaps I should add, I'm interested also, if that's the case, in why that needs to be or was chosen to be the way the language works.

Comment: The implicit instantiation of polytypes and type inference makes such instances cumbersome. E.g. assume `class C a where foo::a -> Int` -- does `foo id` call `instance C (Int -> Int)` or `instance C (forall a. a->a)` ? If we had explicit type arguments as in System F, it would be the second one. With implicit type args, it's much less clear. Now, assume that we have a complex expression instead of `id`: it starts becoming too complex. The current mechanism is driven by type constructors, and `forall` can not be regarded as a tycon since it gets instantiated implicitly.

Comment: As an alternative approach, check out Agda's [implicit instance arguments](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php?n=ReferenceManual.InstanceArguments).

Answer (score 3):

First, there's a trick which allows you to write some instances for universally quantified types: we remove the `forall`-s from the instance head, and introduce type equality constraints to whatever types we want to instantiate the variables. In our case:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, FlexibleInstances, TypeFamilies #-}

instance (a ~ String, Show t) => Show (a -> (t -> a) -> (a -> a -> a) -> a) where
  show t = t "nil" show (\l r -> "(" ++ l ++ ", " ++ r ++ ")")

-- show (fork empty (fork (leaf ()) empty)) == "(nil, ((), nil))"
```

This works because the instance head implicitly quantifies the variable for us. Of course, if we want to instantiate a polymorphic type to several different types then this trick might not be applicable.

On another note, if  GHC allowed polymorphic types in instances, that wouldn't be useful, because GHC doesn't support impredicative instantiation (and the `ImpredicativeTypes` pragma doesn't actually work). For example, `Show (forall a. t)` doesn't imply `Show [forall a. t]`, because `[forall a. t]` isn't valid to begin with. Also, class constraints are kinded in the same system as regular type constructors (except that they return in kind [`Constraint`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/constraint-kind.html)), so `Show (forall a. t)` is similarly invalid without impredicative instantiation.